# Unable to retrieve data using whereLessThan() and whereGreaterThan() in Firestore Query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve the data from Firestore using a query that consists of `whereLessThan()` and `whereGreaterThan()` methids. But when I use the following query it returns me empty snapshot:

```
Query query = firestore.collection("Users").whereLessThan("id",id).whereGreaterThan("id", id).orderBy("id");
```

But when I use only 1 clause it successfully retrives data:

```
Query query = firestore.collection("Users").whereLessThan("id",id); //Working Fine
```

I have also tried by attaching snapshotListener to query:

```
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onEvent( QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,  FirebaseFirestoreException e)
       {
           if(queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
               Toast.makeText(RetrieveUserActivity.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   });
```

This shows Toast of No Data Found.

Here is my database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you are trying to exclude a single user with a specific `id` from your `Users` collection. If so, you should change the logic of your code because unfortunately, you cannot achieved this in the way you do. That's why you get an empty snapshot. If you would have been using the following line of code:

```
Query query = firestore.collection("Users")
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("id",id)
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("id", id)
    .orderBy("id");
```

The `snapshot` object will contain only a single result, which is a single user with that particular `id`. The above line of code, could also be written in more simpler way like this:

```
    Query query = firestore.collection("Users")
    .whereEqualTo("id",id)
    .orderBy("id");
```

I gave you this examples to understand better how this methods work. To solve your problem, according to the official documentation regarding [Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore **does not support** the following types of queries:

- > Queries with a **!=** clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example,
  >   although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported,
  >   you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with
  >   the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause
  >   where("age", ">", 30).

So with other words, there is no `!=` (not equal to) operator in Firestore. The only option that you have is to split your query into a `greater-than` and a `less-than` query and then it will work perfectly fine

Comment: According the official docs- For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30). How can I combine these two queries?

Comment: This sounds as another demand that can be basically considered another question that I cannot answer just in a comment. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I was already aware of the thing that you told me. So, in order to solve that problem of retrieval of data with not equal to I was trying to use that query using whereEqualTo() and whereLessThat() methods. As its wriiten in documentation that combine these two to get the result.

Comment: No, you were not aware since you have tried to use both methods in a single statement, which is not possible in Firestore. You also said that it returns you an empty snapshot. So to solve this, you need to have two separate queries and then combine them. As I asked you earlier, please post another question so I can responde, (me or other user) to your question with the solution of combining two quries, which is obvious that is another question which is not related to this one.